# What weight to use for using NAMCS and NHAMCS together?

Tags: sampling, descriptive-statistics, survey, ratio, survey-sampling

I am interested in analyzing the total prescription of aspirin in NAMCS and NHAMCS (https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/ahcd/index.htm) during a given year for all visits. NAMCS and NHAMCS each had a weight and their weights were quite different, where I noted that neither weight sums to US population. However, NAMCS and NHAMCS were sampled independent of each other. This leads me to think combining them is fine. However, combined sample will weight observations differently for ratio estimate. For total estimates, it seems this is perfectly fine.

$Q:$ Am I wrong about combining NAMCS and NHAMCS without adjusting weights?